# Firestore security rule works for delete and update but not for read?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I have the following functions in my security rules

```
function isSignedIn() {
    return request.auth != null;
}

function getRole(workspaceId) {
    return get(/databases/$(database)/documents/roles/$(workspaceId)/members/$(request.auth.uid)).data.role
}

     
function isOneOfRolesOtherResource(rsc, array) {
  return isSignedIn() && (getRole(rsc.data.workspace_id) in array);
}
```

And  the following rules for my tasks collection.

```
match /tasks/{document=**} {
      allow create: if isOneOfRolesOtherResource(request.resource, ['ADMIN', 'MANAGER', 'MEMBER', 'GUEST']);
      allow read: if isOneOfRolesOtherResource(resource, ['ADMIN', 'MANAGER', 'MEMBER', 'GUEST']);
      allow update, delete: if isOneOfRolesOtherResource(resource, ['ADMIN', 'MANAGER', 'MEMBER', 'GUEST']);
}
```

My read, update, and delete rules are exactly the same but for some reason my read rule has insufficient permissions while update and delete work just fine. If I change the read rule to is signed in, I also have no problems. In the firestore playground, the read rule passes. I can't seem to figure out what's going on.

This is my query in my app, again this observer works fine when just using the sign in auth.

```
const query = db
.collection(TASKS_STORENAME)
.where('project_id', '==', activeProject.value.id);



projectTasksObserver = query.onSnapshot(
    (querySnapshot) => {
      querySnapshot.docChanges().forEach((change) => {
        const taskData = change.doc.data() as TaskData;
        const task = Task.deserialize(taskData);
        console.log('task change type:', change.type);
        if (change.type === 'added') {
          addProjectTask(task);
        }
        if (change.type === 'modified') {
          updateProjectTask(task);
        }
        if (change.type === 'removed') {
          removeProjectTask(task);
        }
      });
    }
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out. The problem was my query wasn't specific enough, so google thought I had insufficient permissions.

Adding the workspace filter worked.

```
const query = db
.collection(TASKS_STORENAME)
.where('workspace_id', '==', activeProject.value.workspace_id)
.where('project_id', '==', activeProject.value.id);
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in the scope of the rule. Your `create`, `update` and `delete` rules always target a single document, for which the rules engine can then check if its target resource contains the necessary value.

Your `read` rule covers both `get` (reading a single document) and `list` (querying/reading multiple documents) and in the latter case Firestore would have to check each current and future document, which would be prohibitive for performance. The documentation covers this under [rules are not filters](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-conditions#rules_are_not_filters).

Rules themselves are not filters, but they merely enforce that you're not trying to read data you're not authorized for. The solution is (as I see you just figured out yourself too), to include the same condition in your query that your rules enforce.